# Create DataBase Neo4j with node js

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem to create a db neoj, this my code in my file server.js:

```
var db = require("seraph")({
      server: "http://127.0.0.1:7474",
      endpoint: "data/graph.db",
     user: "neo4j",
    pass: "neo4j"
      })
  , graph = require("neo4jquery").setConnection(db)

  , query = "CREATE (vous:Personne { nom:'Vous' })RETURN vous" ;

  graph.Query(query, false, function(err, list) {
      if (err) {
       // callback(err, void 0);
          console.log("ERROR Execution" + err);
      } else {
        // some stuff here with list 

    console.log("requete executée !");
        var user = list[0];
      }
    });
```

If I connect in http://127.0.0.1:7474 : "Invalid username or password."

When I run server.js it shows me: "ERROR ExecutionError: Invalid username or password."

Although I added these two lines  in "neo4j-server.properties" :

```
org.neo4j.server.credentials=neo4j:neo4j
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.server.extension.auth=/auth
```

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: hi, it is Neo4j 2.3.2